# Incorrect Syntax near WHERE error in generated SQL

Tags: java, sql-server

I am generating the below SQL. From my code I am using a where condition list to collect all the Where logic and insert it after the Join logic is set-up. However, I am getting a very generic syntax error and I can't figure out why. I am pretty sure the logic is properly organized however, when inserting the where statement it throws the syntax error

> Incorrect Syntax near WHERE

The {h-schema} are just generated database and table names.

The code:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ID
FROM (
SELECT 'PREAPPROVAL' AS type, pa.id AS id FROM {h-schema}preapproval AS pa 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}risk_limit AS lim ON pa.limit_id = lim.id 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}desk AS d ON lim.desk_enterprise_id = d.enterprise_id AND CAST(pa.creation_date_time AS date) BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.end_date

WHERE pa.status = 'APPROVED' AND pd.end_date = NULL <-------------------------SYNTAX ERR HERE
OR pa.status = 'DECLINED' AND pa.completion_date_time > '2021-01-28 13:02:13' 
OR pa.status = 'IN_PROGRESS' 
OR pa.creation_date_time > '2021-01-28 13:02:13'

AND COALESCE(lim.policy_enterprise_id, d.policy_enterprise_id) IN (6)
UNION
SELECT 'BREACH' AS type, br.id AS id FROM {h-schema}breach AS br 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}risk_limit AS lim ON br.limit_id = lim.id 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}desk AS d ON lim.desk_enterprise_id = d.enterprise_id 
AND br.reporting_date BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.end_date 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}valid_breach_recommendation AS vbr_approve ON vbr_approve.id = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM {h-schema}valid_breach_recommendation 
WHERE breach_id = br.id AND outcome = 'APPROVE' 
ORDER BY creation_date_time DESC, id DESC) 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}valid_breach_decision AS vbd 
ON vbd.id = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM {h-schema}valid_breach_decision 
WHERE breach_id = br.id 
ORDER BY creation_date_time DESC, id DESC) 
LEFT JOIN {h-schema}breach AS child_br ON br.id = child_br.parent_breach_id 

WHERE br.status = 'APPROVED' AND vbd.end_date = NULL      <--------------------SYNTAX ERR HERE
OR br.status = 'DECLINED' AND br.completion_date_time > '2021-01-28 13:02:14' 
OR br.status = 'IN_PROGRESS' 
OR br.creation_date_time > '2021-01-28 13:02:14' 

AND child_br.id IS NULL 
AND CASE br.status 
WHEN 'IN_PROGRESS' THEN vbr_approve.start_date 
WHEN 'APPROVED' THEN vbd.start_date 
WHEN 'CANCELLED' THEN vbd.start_date 
ELSE NULL 
END IS NOT NULL AND COALESCE(lim.policy_enterprise_id, d.policy_enterprise_id) IN (6)
) AS issue
```

Comment: There's `= NULL` instead of `IS NULL`.

Comment: Did you try `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` ?  The latter is never valid.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS... and you have no table alias `pd` hence why `pd.end_date` is invalid. So it should probably be `pd.end_date is null`

Comment: I believe this is a Microsoft SQL Server error, not MySQL. Syntax error messages in MySQL include an excerpt of the query following the point where it got confused.

Comment: How are you generating this? With your own solution or a real tool?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I thought I'd figured it out...I didn't. I tried updating to IS NULL. Same error. It is SQL Server. I added the tags in a hurry will update the tags

Comment: The Code is being generated by our own functions. We define the alias before generating the code. The alias isn't the issue. I have other similar querires that work fine.

Comment: Yeah, but the `{h-schema}` prefix makes it hard to see what the actual error is in SSMS, if you remove it in SSMS the actual error becomes obvious.

Comment: In our generator we have this statement addTable(leftJoin(sqlTable("preapproval_decision").as("pd")).on(...). The {h-schema} is referencing this. I can replace it with the table reference in SQL SSMS and it'll run the query.

Comment: I LIED. You were right! it was causing the issue. I removed that statement and it generated the sql correctly but it's working in my other queries so I didn't think it was the issue. I apologize

Comment: No t the {h-Schema} The issue was with pd.end_date being invalid. Thank you

Comment: Using both AND and OR in your WHERE clause without parentheses is often a logic problem. Beware!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually version issue. In latest version of SQL support like
create procedure sp_name
(
@name varchar(50) NULL
)
...

But the older version of SQL doesn't support with this way. For older version we need to provide '=NULL'

Answer (score -1):

There is some syntax error due to {h-schema}, remove {h-schema} and your code has no syntax error. Remove {h-schema} and your code works fine.

Comment: As per OPs comments, this is generated and replaced and is not the issue.

Comment: This is really a comment. But don't equate "compile without error" and "working fine". There are other issues that will prevent the query from returning correct results.